# Showing uniform convergence by showing the derivative is negative

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I wish to show the uniform convergence of the $f_n$ to $f$ on the interval $[1, \infty)$ where $$f_n(x) = (n/x^3)(\sin(x/n))$$ and $$f(x) = 1/x^2.$$

My idea is as follows:
First, I show that $f-f_n$ is always nonnegative.

Second, I show that $(f-f_n)’$ is negative for any $x\geq 1$.

From here, we see that $f-f_n$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. Thus, $f-f_n$ obtains its maximum value in $[1,\infty)$ at 1, namely $ 1- n \sin(1/n)$. Since this value tends to 0 as $n$ approaches infinity and for each $n$ this is the maximum difference between $f_n$ and $f$, the convergence is uniform.

However, I am stuck in showing the derivative is negative for $x\geq 1$. This is equivalent to showing that
$$ (3 n \sin(x/n) - x (\cos(x/n) + 2))<0 $$ for $x\geq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your argument does not work because $3\sin y-y\sin y -2y \sim y-y^{2} >0$ when $y>0$ is near $0$.

Comment: Ah, I mistyped. $y \sin y$ should be $y \cos y$. I shall edit. However, I still only need the values of the derivative to be nonpositive at values greater than or equal to 1. Any ideas how to resolve this?